# how to improve numerical stability

Tags: numerical-methods

I'm trying to improve the numerical stability of $(x+1)(x-1)(x-2)/(x^2+4)$. I already  have turned it into $(x+1)(x-1)/(x+2)$ and NaN if $x=2$. I realize that I can't make it better around $x=-2$ due to bad condition, but I'm still trying to improve it around $x=1$ and $x=-1$, i.e. I don't want to take the difference between two numbers that are almost equal.

Comment: $\frac{(x+1)(x-1)(x-2)}{x^2+4} \neq \frac{(x+1)(x-1)}{x+2}$

Comment: I think OP meant $x^2-4$ in the denominator.

Comment: It would make more sense to explain that you are concerned with the "stability" of numerically evaluating the rational expression (and to explain or correct your claim that you "turned it into" the other rational expression).  Did you in fact intend the denominator originally to be $x^2-4$?

Answer (score 1):

You can't unless you know something about $x$ that lets you add or subtract $1$ analytically.  If I just tell you $x=0.99999953243$ you will lose six digits when you subtract it from $1$.  If I tell you that $x$ came from a calculation you might be able to look at the calculation and do better.  For example, if $x=\sqrt{1-\frac 1{1,000,000}}$ you can compute the Taylor series of the square root around $1$, subtract the $1$ analytically, and have good accuracy for the result.